# Can you call a single tuple a "relation"?

Tags: terminology, relations

A relation is a set of tuples, and a subset of the Cartesian product. But can the term "relation", perhaps informally, also mean a single tuple?

(I'm grading a database exam. As you might now, relational databases are inspired by mathematical relations. A table in the database is called a relation, and it is a set of tuples. But one student wrote that a relation is a single tuple, and before I deduct points I'd like to be sure that he doesn't know more math than I do.)

Answer (score 3):

A single tuple is not a relation. But a *set* containing a single tuple is, of course, a relation.

That is, $(1,1)$ *is not* a relation on $\mathbb R$. However, $\{(1,1)\}$ *is* a relation on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Or to make the same.point in the context of.relational.databases: a row is not a table, but one may have a table that _contains_ only a single row.